# The usage of 'give a crap'

Tags: phrase-usage, spoken-english, informal-language

I heard the sentence below in the TV show, "Two Broke Girls".

> I don't give a crap what you said.

I think it should add an 'about'. Then it becomes:

> I don't give a crap **about** what you said.

What would be the correct/idiomatic way to say it?

Also, I see lots of similar phrases: give a darn, give a damn, give a shit, give a f*ck, and etc. Do these phrases mean exactly the same?

Comment: Either way would be idiomatic.  They're on a scale from mild to severe. "darn"  and "hoot" would be mild. "fuck" would be at the severe end of the scale.

Comment: Either way is correct although I think the original version, without "about" is actually more idiomatic.  There's a slight difference in meaning, I think.  Think of the first version as  "I don't care what you said": it means "It does not matter what you said or did not say, the fact of your speech is not important."  But "I don't give a crap about what you said" implies "I don't care about the thing you were referring to in your speech."

Comment: what about "I don't give a crap it" vs "I don't give a crap about it"?

Comment: Ah, good point!  In that case you *do* have to say "about".  I'm not sure I can explain exactly why, but some phrasings require "about" and some don't.

Comment: Also, I see "what do I care?", why not "what do I care about?"? And how about "I don't care/give a crap the reason." vs "I don't care/give a crap about the reason"?

Comment: @dan - It wouldn’t be: “What do I care **about**?” Rather, it could be paraphrased as: “How much do you think I care?” (Or maybe just: “Do I care?”) _“What do I care?”_ is a rhetorical question, and the unstated answer is, “I **don’t** care.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one a whole family of verbs and verbal expressions with similar meaning: "care", "mind", "give a toss/crap/shit/hoot/damn/fuck". They can all take an indirect object with "about". But they can also take a direct object, but only if it is an "indirect question" - a clause introduced with an interrogative word:

> I don't care what he said.
>
> I don't care when you finish.
>
> I don't care whether it's ready.

"Know" is similar, but it can take other kinds of direct object as well.

Comment: I think "know" is a bit different, because we can say 'I know it.', but can we say 'I don't care it.'? Can you also help to answer my this question above? *"Also, I see "what do I care?", why not "what do I care about?"? And how about "I don't care/give a crap the reason." vs "I don't care/give a crap about the reason"?"*

Comment: I said that "know" ws different in that it can take other kinds of direct object. As for "What do I care?" single question words can behave like indirect questions in many contexts, eg: "I asked him why." "I told him when". "The reason" is not an indirect question, so cannot be a direct object of these expressions. .